# How can I get difference ratio using “diff” or other command?

Tags: diff

I have two files with thousands lines. I want to get their differences ratio in lines/bytes using **diff**, **vimdiff** or other commands, even regardless of the specific differences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a tool called `diffstat` that sounds like what you're looking for.

```
$ diff <file1> <file2> | diffstat
```

#### Example

```
$ diff afpuri.c afpuri1.c | diffstat
 unknown |   53 ++++++++++++++++++++---------------------------------
 1 file changed, 20 insertions(+), 33 deletions(-)
```

This can be used for `diff` output which includes multiple files in a tree as well.

#### References

- [How to get diff to report summary of new, changed and deleted lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767198/how-to-get-diff-to-report-summary-of-new-changed-and-deleted-lines)

Comment: Good to know, though this will only work on plaintext files based on my experiment.

Answer (score 2):

**My math might be a bit off, but I believe you asked for a ratio, and I believe this produces a ratio.**

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# File 1 contains 1,2,3,4,5 on new lines
# File 2 contains 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 on new lines.

# Compare differentials side-by-side
diff -y 1 2 > diff

# Print lines to file which do not contain ">" prefix.
sed 's/[ ]/d' diff > MATCHES

# Print lines to file which do contain ">" prefix.
sed '/[>]/!d' diff > DIFFS

# Count lines in file that contains MATCHES between Versions of Files 1,2.
MATCHES=$(wc -l MATCHES | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')

# Count lines in file that DID NOT MATCH between Version of Files 1,2.
DIFFS=$(wc -l DIFFS | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')

# Sed here is stripping all but the number of lines in file.

RATIO=$(echo "$MATCHES / $DIFFS" | bc -l)

# To get the ratio, we are echoing the #of_matches and the #of_diffs to
# the bc -l command which will give us a float, if we need it.
echo "You've got:" $RATIO "differential."

# Bytes...
# stat -c%s prints bytes to variable
MATCHES=$(stat -c%s MATCHES)
DIFFS=$(stat -c%s DIFFS)

RATIO_BYTE=$(echo "$MATCHES / $DIFFS" | bc -l)
echo "Let Ratio in Bytes be" $RATIO_BYTE
# Again, we divide the matches by the diffs to reach the "ratio" of
# differences between the files.
```

Comment: The accepted answer is good enough for ratio computing. Thanks anyway!

Comment: $> diffstat is definitely the shell utility for this.